# How to compose these two functions

Tags: haskell

I know the title is a bit unclear, the problem is:

Suppose I have a function of type `a -> c`, another function of type `b -> d`, how can I get a function of type `(a -> b) -> (c -> d)`, or is it impossible in general?

---

Probably I should provide some background. I asked this question because I have difficulty solving Exercise 9 from the paper [Fun with phantom types](http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/ralf.hinze/publications/With.pdf).

```
data Type t where
  ...
  RFun :: Type a -> Type b -> Type (a -> b)
```

And the `tequal`function

```
tequal :: Type t -> Type u -> Maybe (t -> u)
...
tequal (RFun a b) (RFun c d) = -- should do something with (tequal a c) (tequal b d)
```

So the problem boils down to composing `a -> c` and `b -> d` to get `(a -> b) -> (c -> d)`

Comment: And what is that? A function that take function and return function? Did you really mean first argument will be `(a -> b)`?

Comment: Yes, it is a function that takes a function and returns another function, just reading from the type.

Comment: Just the resulting type is completely pointless, cause you have some different functions there.

Comment: It is possible to a function in Haskell take another function as a parameter. Now, do you want to return a function to apply somewhere else?

Comment: I've edited my question to give some background

Comment: Just a hint because I think it's all you'll need. You have options other than recursing on `tequal a c`, `tequal b d`. One of these options will give you pieces of the correct shape to compose to get `(a -> b) -> (c -> d)`.

Comment: What you are asking for in the first part is impossible (and could be proved through Curry-Howard). But the second part is solvable -- I strongly second the suggestion of @ReidBarton. You can be more creative in your recursive calls.

Comment: After a quick look at the paper you've mentioned I have another suggestion: probably, you should use another type for function representation? Anyway, all you need for the function type is to store the types of the domain and codomain, thus this type is very similar to the one for pair:
    `RFun (Type a) (Type b)`
Thus the `tequal` implementation will be quit trivial.
As for your original question, I'm totally agree with @max-taldykin, it's impossible.

Answer (score 3):

This is impossible.

Suppose you have desired function `f :: (a -> b) -> (c -> d)`.

You can simplify it's type to `(a -> b) -> c -> d` (See [why](https://wiki.haskell.org/Partial_application)).

How could implementation of `f` look like? It has first argument of type `a -> b` and second of type `c`:

```
f ab c = ...
```

What can you do with `ab`? It's a function but you can't apply it because you don't have anything of type `a` (except `_|_`). And even if you have functions `g :: a -> c` and `h :: b -> d` they are of no use because you don't have anything of type `a` or `b` and you can't compose them.

So the only valid implementation is something like

```
f ab = undefined
```

or

```
f = undefined
```

---

Regarding second part of your question, it seems that you can recursively use `tequal` to check function type equality: types `a -> c` and `b -> d` are equal only if `a` = `b` and `c` = `d` (this is valid because toy type system from the paper don't have type variables).

Here is a sketch of implementation:

```
tequal (RFun a c) (RFun b d)
  = liftM2 func (tequal a b) (tequal c d)
```

You can note that the code is almost identical to the case for `RPair`. This is somehow related to currying.

Answer (score 3):

As a small supplement to max taldykin's answer,

Given

```
f :: (a -> c) -> (b -> d) -> (a -> b) -> (c -> d)
f ac bd ab = ???
```

there's really only one way to combine the arguments

```
bd . ab :: a -> d
```

but now we're stuck! We have no way to construct a `c -> d` from any combination of `a -> c`, `b -> d`, `a -> b`, or `a -> d`.

On the other hand, if we had a `c -> a` then we could construct a

```
f :: (c -> a) -> (b -> d) -> (a -> b) -> (c -> d)
f ca bd ab = bd . ab . ca
```

By the way, it can be very helpful to get out a pen and paper and draw some arrows and try to connect them into a diagram:

[image]

If you try to do the same for `f :: (a -> c) -> (b -> d) -> (a -> b) -> (c -> d)` then you'll see that there's no way to draw a diagram that connects `c -> d`:

[image]

and now we have no way to connect the dots.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are looking for **Higher Order Functions**, which is basically a function taking functions as parameters or returning other functions.

For example to illustrate a higher order function, you can define the following functions:

```
f0 :: Int -> Int
f0 x = 0

f1 :: a -> a
f1 x = x

f2 :: (a -> a) -> a -> a
f2 f a = f(a)

f3 :: (a -> a) -> (a -> a)
f3 f = f1
```

Notice that f2 takes a **function** and apply it to the second parameter and that f3 takes a **function** and **return** the function  f1.

If you execute f2(f3(f0)) 5, it is going to return 5 to you.

**Step-by-step**

**1- f2(f3(f0)) 5** f3 takes a function (f0) and will return f1.

**2- f2(f1) 5** f2 takes a function (f1) and applies it to the second parameter (5)

**3- f1(5)** f1 is applied to 5.

Comment: I am very familiar with higher-order functions. The question I have is how to compose them in the way I specify through type. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I see. I started writing before you edited the answer, my bad here. I am looking for some other way to solve this now.